# My jQuery code is not working efficiently to open and close mobile menu bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Pls I need help with the nav bar(mobile view) I want to use jQuery to open and close the menu. This is my first every web dev project

https://github.com/alwayswantedtocode/my-first-web-dev-project

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You can delete `});
$(document).ready(()=>{` you only need one

Answer (score 0):

.toggle() isn't enough!

Use remove/add class instead.

```
$('.navigation').removeClass('').addClass('')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/drmtpocn/1/

Comment: it worked but when i close the menu bar it moves to the left of my screen before disappearing.

Comment: @OSATOHAMHENSAMUELEBHOHON row 294: Change right:-250 ; to right:-250px; or else the syntax is wrong (in css)

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're defining your $(Document).ready function on each function, there is no need for that considering you will have most of your JQuery functions run inside it, so you can only define it at the start of your project. You will then place the other functions inside of only that one document.ready function.

If you want a simple way of resolving this you can use the following code:

```
   $(document).ready(() => {

    $('.menu-Icon span').click(() => {
        $('.navigation').addClass('open');
        $(".navigation").removeClass('close');

    });
    
    $(".X-close").click(() => {
        $(".navigation").toggleClass('close');
    });
});
```

this will remove the "close" class every time you open it and it will add the open class, when you close the menu after, it will then re-add the close class.

There is a another option with a built-in JQuery function that might make it look a bit better than just appearing.

You would put the following into your JQuery

```
  $(document).ready(() => {

    $('.menu-Icon').click(() => {
        $('.navigation').slideDown();

     

    });
    
    $(".X-close").click(() => {
        $('.navigation').slideUp();
    });
})
```

;

and your CSS on line 304 would change, here is the edited snippet.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:991px) /* Line 290 */
{
    .header .navigation{ 
        position: fixed;
        right:-250 ;/*initially zero*/
        width:250px;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto; 
        background-color: #3e5e75;
        /* opacity: 0.75; */
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        padding: 15px 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease ;
       display: none; /*Changed element line 304*/
       /* Changed from visibility to display */
        
    }
```

For more details on the jQuery slideUP/slideDown please follow the link below :)

[SlideDown](https://api.jquery.com/slidedown/)